What does 好きなだけ mean here?
The sentence: 全部ママが洗うから好きなだけでね
And this is said by 'mama' herself while giving her kid a bath. Does it mean she just really likes washing? But if that's the case, then the から confuses me. Or is she saying to the kid "since I'm taking care of the washing, do whatever you want"? There are other posts on the topic but they're structured differently and I don't think they're the same.

好きなだけ means something like "to your hearts content."  Context appears to be missing.  To me, this sounds like Mama is saying "I'll wash it all; so do ??? to your hearts content." where "???" is determined by the context.

Your statement is either something that can't be understood without context, or there are errors in your transcription. In what situation was it said? Without further clarification, it would be difficult to provide an explanation.
